# How to update starred value of a contact in android using ContactsContract URI

Tags: android, contacts

I have a question.
How to update the starred value of contact if we are having name or number of that particular contact. Please note that this should be done using ContactsContract URI as PEOPLE URI is deprecated. I tried out different solutions, but nothing seems to be working fine.
Need help. Looking for best possible solution.

Comment: Somebody please help....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally I got a solution :)

Using Contacts URI we can update starred value of a contact.

values.put(Contacts.STARRED, 1);

getContentResolver().update(Contacts.CONTENT_URI, values, Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + "= ?", strNamevalue);

it will work

Comment: I used Contacts._ID instead of name, which seems to be a better way to do it.. worked for me. Thanks!