# Mark existing contact as Favourite or Starred?

Tags: android, android-contacts

How do I, via code, mark an existing contact as Favourite or Starred?

Answer (score 4):

If you don't mean programmatically, just go to 'people', then click on the contact who you want to favourite. Then simply click on the star in the top right corner. This is how I do it in android ICS. See this link:
http://www.androidcentral.com/android-101-favoriting-and-un-favoriting-contacts

Programmatically, there is a column in the contacts provider called "STARRED". To make a specific contact a favourite, you would have to change this value to 1.

There is a similar question here:
[How to update starred value of a contact in android using ContactsContract URI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10583893/how-to-update-starred-value-of-a-contact-in-android-using-contactscontract-uri)

For more information on the contacts content provider, see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Contacts.html